# Why is mysql logging to syslog?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, logs

I have installed Multiple MySQL instances and i have two configuration files one for each one is using default location of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

other server i have started like

```
root@ABC-240:/usr/local/mysql# bin/mysqld_safe  --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/binary_my.cnf &


root@ABC-240:/usr/local/mysql# 120104 10:19:34 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
120104 10:19:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
```

I have set the error log in both of the configuration files but one of them as above is logging to syslogs.

Why is it like that?

Comment: what does the `/etc/mysql/binary_my.cnf` file contain?

Comment: @Raihan:  actually its a file like my.cnf but having different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that both instances of MySQL are trying to record log entries to the same location (same file).

I do not think mysql allows more that one error log per MySQL instance.

Here is something further on [**using error log with mysqld and mysqld_safe**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html):

> No error log renaming occurs when the logs are flushed in any case if
>   the server is not writing to a named file.
>
> If you use mysqld_safe to start mysqld, mysqld_safe arranges for
>   mysqld to write error messages to a log file or (as of MySQL 5.1.20)
>   to syslog:
>
> • Before 5.1.20, mysqld_safe behavior is to log to a file, using the
>   default error log file if the --log-error option is not given to
>   mysqld_safe. Otherwise, mysqld_safe uses the file name specified using
>   --log-error=file_name.
>
> • From 5.1.20 on, mysqld_safe has two additional error-logging
>   options, --syslog and --skip-syslog.
>
> In 5.1.21 and up, the default with no logging options is
>   --skip-syslog, which is compatible with the default behavior of writing an error log file for releases prior to 5.1.20. To explicitly
>   specify use of an error log file, specify --log-error=file_name to
>   mysqld_safe, and mysqld_safe will arrange for mysqld to write messages
>   to a log file. To use syslog instead, specify the --syslog option.
>
> In 5.1.20 only, the following conditions apply: 1) The default is to
>   use syslog, which is not compatible with releases prior to 5.1.20. 2)
>   Logging to syslog may fail to operate correctly in some cases; if so,
>   use --skip-syslog or --log-error.
>
> For logging to syslog, messages from mysqld_safe and mysqld are
>   written with a tag of mysqld_safe and mysqld, respectively. As of
>   MySQL 5.1.21, to specify a suffix for the tag, use --syslog-tag=tag,
>   which modifies the tags to be mysqld_safe-tag and mysqld-tag.
>
> If you specify --log-error in an option file in a section that mysqld
>   reads, mysqld_safe also will find and use the option.

Since you started mysqld_safe to start mysqld, you just need to start mysqld_safe and explicitly choose a separate file for the error of the other MySQL Instance using the -`-log-error` option.